# Atom commander in atom editor shows empty gray field

Tags: plugins, editor, atom-editor

I installed the [Atom Commander plugin](https://atom.io/packages/atom-commander) in Atom on OSX and it works fine with SFTP. When clicking on the 'Option' (not the 'Alt/Cmd' key as stated) I activate the menu and can select options and add an SFTP server. Then a two pane browser is shown but when I click on a file or folder a large empty gray field is shown on the bottom of the screen and when I click again (defocus the Atom Commander) the gray field disappears.

Trying to hide it by the Element Inspector in dev mode had no success as the gray field is beyond the editor workspace.

Very weird behavior and it wastes a considerable portion of the screen.

This only happens with this plugin and no other parts or plugins of Atom.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The `atom` tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to `atom-editor`. Hope this helps your question get the right eyes on it, for further information about tags have a read of [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [color-picker](https://github.com/thomaslindstrom/color-picker) package installed? If you do then this has been reported back towards the end of 2015 in [Atom Commander Issue #12](https://github.com/morassman/atom-commander/issues/12), and was subsequently fixed in [Color Picker Issue #143](https://github.com/thomaslindstrom/color-picker/issues/143) and released in v2.1.1 of the latter package.

If you **don't** have color-picker installed then it is possible that another package is causing the problem, I would recommend using the [bug-report](https://atom.io/packages/bug-report) package to generate a bug report that you paste into a [New Issue](https://github.com/morassman/atom-commander/issues/new).

Comment: Indeed, disabling the Color Picker solves the problem.

Comment: I hesitate to mention it as it seems somewhat of a tangent, I have recently switched to using [chrome-color-picker](https://atom.io/packages/chrome-color-picker) over `color-picker` in Atom.  Personally, I find it much cleaner and easier to use.